Can Apache Nifi Expression be used dynamically when accessing json values from an attribute?
In Apache Nifi I have an attribute timestamps which has a value:
[{"primary":{"apu":"2023-09-22T09:50:31.189489463Z","sop":"2024-03-15T08:20:02.540443877Z","zeq":"2023-09-22T09:50:31.189489463Z","wur":"2024-03-14T20:20:02.525785598Z"}}].
How can I access a nested key value based on another attribute value?
In an UpdateAttribute processor, a hard-coded way of accessing the timestamp of wur would work like: ${timestamps:jsonPath('$.[0].primary.wur')}.
But I would like to access the value based on another attribute, i.e. I have the name of the key in an attribute keyname which has value wur.
By my intuition, using UpdateAttribute and adding a new attribute/property should work with ${timestamps:jsonPath('$.[0].primary.${keyname}')} but obviously my intuition is wrong.
Can my goal be achieved with UpdateAttribute (which would be the simplest way I think) or should I do a workaround if dynamic evaluation of jsonpaths is not plausible?

Well, it seem my intuition was right after all.
Just had to triplecheck quotation marks and string cases from original non-pseudonymised nifi flow.

and empty old flowfiles in the queues

prosessGroup as json: https://pastebin.com/UvPApra2
